# Automatically adding headers to python Requests requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to create a rest api client for talking to one of our services. Every request needs to include an authorisation header which is compromised of Epoch times, request verb, data, path etc.

I'm trying to use the python requests module as seamlessly as possible, but am unsure the best way to "inject" a header into every request.

There seems to be a concept of "hooks" in requests, but currently there is only a "response" hook.

I was considering extending the Session object and overriding the "send" method, adding the header and then passing it up to the super (Session.send) method.

My Python isn't fantastic when it comes to OOP and Inheritance, but this is what I have tried

```
 class MySession(Session):
    def __init__(self, access_id=None, access_key=None):
        self.access_id = access_id
        self.access_key = access_key
        super(MySession, self).__init__()

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        method = request.method
        path = urlparse(request.url).path

        request.headers['Authorization'] = self.__create_security_header(method, path)
        request.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"

        return Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need to override the `send` method, since you have already overriden the `__init__`.

```
class MySession(Session):

    def __init__(self, access_id=None, access_key=None):
        super(MySession, self).__init__()
        self.access_id, self.access_key = access_id, access_key

        # provided __create_security_header method is defined
        self.headers['Authorization'] = self.__create_security_header(method, path)
        self.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
```

Most likely that should do.

Comment: Will that create a new header for each request though? as the header is a hash of method, uri etc it needs to be generated just before the request is sent.